# dpkg processing issues

Tags: dpkg

I have been trying to install a few prog and it doesn't seem to work. For example with skype, I use the

```
sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.de
```

and it all seems to work fine apart from at the end where it says

```
dpkg: error processing package skype (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 skype
```

The whole code is here:

```
sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
(Reading database ... 165439 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking skype (4.3.0.37-1) over (4.3.0.37-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of skype:
 skype depends on libc6 (>= 2.3.6-6~).
 skype depends on libc6 (>= 2.7).
 skype depends on libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1).
 skype depends on libqt4-dbus (>= 4:4.5.3).
 skype depends on libqt4-network (>= 4:4.8.0).
 skype depends on libqt4-xml (>= 4:4.5.3).
 skype depends on libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1).
 skype depends on libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0).
 skype depends on libqtwebkit4 (>= 2.2~2011week36).
 skype depends on libstdc++6 (>= 4.2.1).
 skype depends on libx11-6.
 skype depends on libxext6.
 skype depends on libxss1.
 skype depends on libxv1.
 skype depends on libssl1.0.0.
 skype depends on libpulse0.
 skype depends on libasound2-plugins.

dpkg: error processing package skype (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 skype
```

This does it with other prog like Ubuntu Tweak as well.

Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're installing a .deb file that has dependencies. See this section from your output:

```
 skype depends on libc6 (>= 2.3.6-6~).
 skype depends on libc6 (>= 2.7).
 skype depends on libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1).
 skype depends on libqt4-dbus (>= 4:4.5.3).
 skype depends on libqt4-network (>= 4:4.8.0).
 skype depends on libqt4-xml (>= 4:4.5.3).
 skype depends on libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1).
 skype depends on libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0).
 skype depends on libqtwebkit4 (>= 2.2~2011week36).
 skype depends on libstdc++6 (>= 4.2.1).
 skype depends on libx11-6.
 skype depends on libxext6.
 skype depends on libxss1.
 skype depends on libxv1.
 skype depends on libssl1.0.0.
 skype depends on libpulse0.
 skype depends on libasound2-plugins.
```

In this output you can see some of your installed packages that are old, like `libc6` asking for a new version `>= 2.3.6-6~`, and some missing packages: the ones without specified version, which means they're not installed - like `libx11-6`.

Usually install the list of missing packages using `apt-get` (like `sudo apt-get install libxx11-6`) would solve the problem. But a package asking you to upgrade the `libc` is not usual: `libc` is one of the main libraries of Unix systems.

Or you never update your system, or you're running a different version of Ubuntu.

Had you updated your system with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`?

Are you using other Ubuntu version then `precise`? (As your skype deb installer is tagged with `precise`).

Comment: Hi Rael,I am using the latest version of Ubuntu. It just had to actually update the apt-get update did the trip.

Comment: @user350501 So, Mark an answer as correct, please.

Answer (score 1):

If you install a local .deb file, dpkg does not automatically resolve the dependencies. To resolve those automatically, you could use gdebi to install local .deb packages. Install it with

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

if it is installed, go to the folder where you have the .deb file and type

```
sudo gdebi skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
```

dependencies shoud now be resolved and skype installed.

Comment: this worked once I ran the update. thanks a lot Bram

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. It was fixed by enabling Canonical partners software site and after that I was able to finish Skype installation.